# Tsql Inserting Unordered Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, sequence

I'm trying to insert an unordered sequence (list) into 2 kind of table explained here:

1. Table has one `INT` column
2. Table has several columns, one of them is an `INT` column (which I will use to insert the data)

So, here is the example;

List; (1, 3, 55, 3, 56456, 45)
Table; (Value INT)

I'm not looking for *any solution*, but a solution which is not including 'parse, split etc.' operations.

Expected solution:

```
INSERT INTO Table(Value)
VALUES(anyList)
```

Expected solution 2:

```
INSERT INTO Table(Value)
VALUELIST(anyList)
```

OR
    INSERT INTO Table(Value)
    VALUETABLE(anyList)

Comment: provide your expected output...

Comment: INSERT INTO Table(Value) VALUES(anyList)

Comment: @NewPHPer So you are really answering Ajay's hint just with the repetition of something written in your question already... Really: Read [How to ask a good sql question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056) and [How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly insert like following.

```
INSERT INTO Table(Value)
VALUES (1, 3, 55, 3, 56456, 45)
```

You will get following error.

> Msg 110, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 There are fewer columns in the
>   INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The
>   number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns
>   specified in the INSERT statement.

SQL Server will only accept your Insert if you give like following.

```
INSERT INTO Table(Value)
VALUES (1),(3),(55), (3), (56456), (45)
```

If you are getting the list as a string, in that case you need to convert it into appropriate format before inserting, like following.

```
DECLARE @xml as xml
DECLARE @list as varchar(max)
SET @list='(1, 3, 55, 3, 56456, 45)'
set @list = REPLACE(REPLACE(@list,'(',''),')','')

SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@list,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)

INSERT INTO [Table](Value)
SELECT N.value('.', 'int') as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)
```

Comment: Thank you. First approach is a good way to insert list of data plus useful. However, I'm looking for something different. Like; INSERT INTO Table(Value) VALUELIST(anyList)

Comment: You can create a table valued function and insert it from that. It can be re-used where ever you want.

Comment: @NewPHPer And again the only additional information is exactly the same you have given already. A former POTUS would say: "Read my lips": You are absolutely unclear on what you need. That's not the audience's fault....